# Link to specific page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create link in title of post that opens new page with this post.
I tried `<%= link_to post.title, posts_path(path) %>`, but getting error

```
undefined local variable or method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbf134f2b88>:0x007fbf13c17d78>
```

What am i doing wrong?

rake:routes:

```
 posts_index GET    /posts/index(.:format)         posts#index
               posts_new GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
            posts_create POST   /posts/create(.:format)        posts#create
                         GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                    root        /                              home#index
                    root        /                              home#index
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like? Could you paste the result of `rake routes` in your question?

Comment: Btw, there's no route which produces `posts_path` in routes file to begin with...

Comment: there is route posts, and path its built in feature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to go to the show action, it's enough to write

```
<%= link_to post.title, post %>
```

Which is the same as

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>
```

Take a look a the doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Is the name of your model `Post` or `Posts`?

Comment: Model name is Post, contoller: Posts_controller

Comment: Did you use scaffold? If not, run `rails generate scaffold Post name:string` in a different (dummy) project and check out the differences to your code.

Comment: Did same as in new project with scaffold, but still have same error

Comment: I was missing `get "posts/:id" => "posts#show", :as => :post` in my routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link to a singular post but used the plural form of the route helper, which does not take an object. Use `post_path`:

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(path) %>
```

The plural form is to list all the resources at that url. The singular form is for showing ONE resource.

See this guide on [rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add this link to my show page

```
<%= link_to 'Write a Review', new_comic_review_review_path(@comic_review)%>
```